# How to make highchart bubble chart color active of clicked bubble

Tags: highcharts

I have bubble chart in highchart plugin,Here my requirement is whenever I click a bubble that bubble should change its color,I mean it should be like active.Here in my example its working fine but I am not able to change the active/highlighted color into red.its showing only black border and grey color.Can anyone please help me on it.Here is my code below.

### HTML

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

### javascript

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts bubbles with radial gradient fill'
    },

    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },

    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            [9, 81, 63],
            [98, 5, 89],
            [51, 50, 73],
            [41, 22, 14],
            [58, 24, 20],
            [78, 37, 34],
            [55, 56, 53],
            [18, 45, 70],
            [42, 44, 28],
            [3, 52, 59],
            [31, 18, 97],
            [79, 91, 63],
            [93, 23, 23],
            [44, 83, 22]
        ],
        color: 'green',
       negativeColor: '#ffffff',
        states: {
            select: {
                color: 'red'
            }
        },
        allowPointSelect: true

    }]

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no `select` state for bubble type chart. They have mentioned `hover` alone in their documentation. That too these options are for the whole series and not for individual points.

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.states

So you could achieve the same effect by using a CSS selector to apply the desired style. You could target the `.highcharts-point-select` class and apply the styles.

Here is a code pen have a look. 
https://codepen.io/samuellawrentz/pen/mjqmVZ

You can do this using Javascript as well, you must manually update the color of the point that is selected. CSS seems pretty easy and straightforward

Comment: Can I make any one bubble selected onload?

Comment: Yeah! I answered it here :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/51640257/8252164