# how to make bubble chart in highchart selected a bubble on load

Tags: highcharts

I have bubble chart in highchart plugin,Here my requirement is anyone bubble should be selected based on clicked value.for ex. if I click 10 different selection and if click on 20 different selection will be there.Can anyone please help me on it.Here is my code below.

### html

```
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
<p class="num">10</p>
<p class="num">20</p>
```

### javascript

```
$("p.num").show();
 $("p.num").click(function(){ 
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        zoomType: 'xy',
         events:{
         load:function(){
      var points = this.series[0].points;
      points[6].select();
    }
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts bubbles with radial gradient fill'
    },

    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },

    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false
    },
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            marker: {
                states: {
                    select: {
                        fillColor : 'orange'

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [9, 81, 103],
            [98, 5, 89],
            [51, 50, 73],
            [41, 22, 14],
            [58, 24, 20],
            [78, 37, 34],
            [55, 56, 53],
            [18, 45, 70],
            [42, 44, 28],
            [3, 52, 59],
            [31, 18, 97],
            [79, 91, 63],
            [93, 23, 23],
            [44, 83, 22]
        ],
        color: 'green',
    }]

})
});
```

### style.css

```
.highcharts-point-select{
stroke: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can do it. I have updated the codepen: https://codepen.io/samuellawrentz/pen/mjqmVZ

You just have to pick a point from the series data and then fire the `select` event on it during chart load. The condition to pick which point to be selected during load must be specified.

For now, I have hard-coded the 6th point to be selected during page load. Check out the codepen for details.

**EDIT:**

As you requested, I have updated the codepen,have a look. The value to be selected during click is given as a `value` attribute in the HTML. Then during the click event we are reading that attribute and selecting the point that was mentioned in the `value` attribute.

`<p class="num" value=5>10</p>`

Here `5th` point will be selected when you click on 10 as the value of the `value` attribute is 5.

Ref: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#select

Comment: Tnak you for your answer

Comment: Can I get the selected  based on click value..here for ex. here onclick of 10, selection should be different,onclick of 20 selection should be different,I have updated the code

Comment: I have edited the answer, please have a look and let me know if you have further doubts :)

Comment: For me values are coming dynamically and also in decimal like <td>0.9</td>,<td>0.2</td>  in this case how to handle here

Comment: What should happen if they click on `<td>0.9</td>`?

Comment: Bubble should be active based on that value

Comment: How are you generating the data? data: [
            [9, 81, 103],
            [98, 5, 89]]. What are those three values? Which data will you get dynamically? The third one in the array? For eg; 103 and 89?

Comment: Yes..this will be third one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177341/discussion-between-samuellawrentz-and-a-prasad). I have updated the codepen

Comment: As of now its fine..if any update I will let you know. Thank you